# Cython: assigning INFINITY or numpy.inf to a typed variable results to 0

Tags: python, numpy, cython, infinity, cythonize

I wish to `cdef` an `INFINITY` constant in a file named `constant.pxd` so that I can `cimport` it elsewhere. Assume in `constant.pxd` we have:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc cimport math

ctypedef np.float32_t dtype_t

cdef dtype_t INF = math.INFINITY if math.INFINITY != 0. else np.float32('inf')
```

This, however, does not work, as for example, in another `.pyx` file:

```
from constant cimport INF
cpdef test():
    return INF
```

Which yields:

```
>> 0.0
```

I also tried to define `INF` directly as `np.float32('inf')` or `np.inf`. However, they all end up with being zeros.

I can, however, define `INF = np.float32('inf')` without typing it, in a `.pyx` file, say `constant.pyx` and use it as expected. I am not clear whether this might result in performing issues, if we have, say:

```
from constant import INF
from constant cimport dtype_t

cdef class A:
    cdef dtype_t data

    def __cinit__(self, dtype_t data):
          self.data = data
# ...
```

And with:

```
from constant import INF

a = A(INF)
```

Comment: I have no problem with your first example. It returns `inf`.

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks! I am not sure what has gone wrong, I still got `0.0`.

Comment: @MSeifert I have found that executable code like this cannot be included in the `.pxd` file (if there are no corresponding `.pyx` file), since `Cython` will treat it as a package but failed. After fixing this, I also got `inf` as desired.

Comment: You can self-answer your question. Make sure you would answer it like you would answer a question from another user though :)